# Fixed points of the ODE $x'(t)=x(t)^2(1-x(t)^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, initial-value-problems

Consider the autonomous differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x(t)), \ \ \ x(t_0)=x_0 $$ where $f(x(t))=(x(t))^2(1-(x(t))^2)$, and let $x(t))$ be the displacement of a particle at time $t$.

The fixed points are $-1$, $0$ and $1$. 
Also $f'(-1)>0 $ so $x=-1$ is an unstable point. Conversely $f'(1)<0 $ so $x=1$ is a stable fixed point.

But my question is $f'(0)=0 $ so is $x=0$ stable or unstable? From drawing the direction field it looks as though if you start near $x=0$ you just move to $x=1$  but apparently if you start near $x=0$ then $x(t)\rightarrow 0 $. Why is this?

Comment: If you start from $x(0)=x_0$ near $0$ with $x_0>0$ (actually, every $x_0>0$), indeed you just move to $x=1$, but if you start from $x(0)=x_0$ near $0$ with $x_0<0$ (actually, every $-1<x_0<0$), you just move to $x=0$.

Comment: Why is that the case though? Why don't you just move past 0 to 1?

Comment: Because solutions never go through fixed points. If they did, this would contradict the uniqueness of the solutions of the differential equations that the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem (aka Picard-Lindelöf) provides.

Comment: In what way exactly does it mean it would contradict the existence and uniqueness theorem?

Comment: Because you know a solution such that $x(0)=0$, which is $x(t)=0$ for every $t$, hence if another solution is such that $x(0)<0$ and $x(t)>0$ for some $t>0$, there exists $s$ in $(0,t)$ such that $x(s)=0$, and one has two different solutions starting from $0$, a contradiction.

Comment: But aren't the initial values different for each solution obtained. The initial conditions for the solution $x(t)=0$ are $x(0)=0$ and the initial conditions for the other solution are $x(s)=0$ so the initial conditions aren't the same so aren't they different initial value problems anyway? So how does it contradict the uniqueness part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47489/discussion-between-ben-and-did).

Comment: Sorry I do not chat. Re the nonuniqueness argument, I suggest that you ponder it a little more before decreeing it does not work (since it is most classic and since it works).

Answer (score 1):

In 1D you may depict the stability by using arrows indicating the sign of the vector field outside of fixed points, whence in what direction a point moves with time. In your case
$$  -\infty \longleftarrow (-1) \longrightarrow (0) \longrightarrow (1) \longleftarrow \infty $$
As Did mentions 0 appears stable from the left but unstable on the right. So the fixed point is neither stable nor unstable. This phenomena happens often when the derivative $\lambda = f'(x_0)$ of your vector field vanishes at a fixed point $f(x_0)=0$. Similar things happens in higher dimensions but with a larger variety of possible phenomena.